# Debugging scheduling while atomic

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, spinlock

I'm assigned to work on a kernel module written by another person, I don't now the code and there is a "scheduling while atomic" bug.

As I understand this is caused by sleeping with in a critical section guarded by spinlock.

Is there anything which can help me to locate the source - the critical section where does the sleep take place or the spinlock which is obtained during the sleep attempt? (generally any recommendation of good article about debugging spinlocks will be appreciated).

Regards
Rene

Comment: Usually if you see that message, the stack trace is printed. So what is the problem with that?

Comment: Yes you are right, in some call traces, there are useful information, but many of them just say:
i386_start_kernel -> start_kernel -> rest_init -> cpu_idle -> cpuidle_idle_call

Comment: Now I got idea - aren't the call traces (above comment) from the cores which didn't fire the bug?

Comment: The backtrace should en up with something like _schedule. Post the full logs with described problem

Comment: About cores - it is possible , check the code

Comment: it's here: http://pastebin.com/Q7JCeXuz , at the end the whole kernel freezes

Comment: Don't you think that your real problem is why this thing is happened acpi_idle_enter->oops_enter and scheduling while atomic is a post factum. Try to disable SCHED_DEBUG maybe the logs picture will change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84100/discussion-between-rene-kolarik-and-alex-hoppus).

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically interrupt any kernel function by using Kprobes:

1. [Kprobes (Kernel probes) documentation](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/kprobes.txt?v=3.13).
2. [An introduction to Kprobes](https://lwn.net/Articles/132196/)

There is a good article about profiling in Linux, but it was written in Russian.

[Mechanisms of profiling in Linux](http://habrahabr.ru/company/metrotek/blog/261003/)

Also, the old school for debugging a Linux Kernel Module(LKM)  is by using the printk() function.

You can write a macro, which will show a name of file, function name, line number.

I wrote a similar macro for myself.

1. [Macros for debugging](https://github.com/Vadim-Stupakov/read-only-fs/blob/master/roflt/roflt_util.h).
2. [Example of how to use this macro.](https://github.com/Vadim-Stupakov/read-only-fs/blob/master/roflt/roflt_rfs.c)

I hope you solve the problem in the near future!